# Find the common values in all subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have a bunch of subqueries that each return a bunch of records with two ID fields. I need to return a list of all ID pairs that exist in all subqueries. I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
SELECT Q1.V1, Q1.V2
FROM ( [SUBQUERY1] ) AS Q1
INNER JOIN ( [SUBQUERY2] ) AS Q2 ON Q2.V1 = Q1.V1 AND Q2.V2 = Q1.V2
INNER JOIN ( [SUBQUERY3] ) AS Q3 ON Q3.V1 = Q2.V1 AND Q3.V2 = Q2.V2
INNER JOIN ( [SUBQUERY4] ) AS Q4 ON Q4.V1 = Q3.V1 AND Q4.V2 = Q3.V2
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is to use `INTERSECT`:

```
[SUBQUERY1]
INTERSECT
[SUBQUERY2]
INTERSECT
[SUBQUERY3]
INTERSECT
[SUBQUERY4]
```

Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Intersect is probably better but you can also use group by along with HAVING COUNT(*) > number_of_subqueries clause.

```
select V1, V2
from 
(
(subquery_1)
union 
(subquery_2)
union 
(subquery_3)
)
group by v1, v2
having count(*) > 3
```